# How to make a div go fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here are two sites http://mpremarks.com and http://thegravity.net/supernova/

The featured image of the first one is not fullscreen while the featured image of the second is.

One of the div on the second site has a class `forcefullwidth_wrapper_tp_banner` with the following parameters:

```
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px
```

If you delete this class the featured image of the second site will become the same as the first one's. So I thought if I just add these parameters to the div on the first site I will get the same result. It didn't happen. I've tried many CSS tricks but they didn't help. So I guess I need some JS here. Please help me figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery methods `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` to get browser's dimensions. Then apply those sizes to your div: `$('div.someClass').width($(window).width())` and `$('div.someClass').height($(window).height())`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the css to

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```